# Drop down menu and database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to discover the best strategy to achieve this goal, so if anyone has a preferred method I'd appreciate it if you could explain how it works and sell it to me as the best option. Basically what I am trying to achieve is a drop down option for pulling reports online. They can be bought in packages which is the drop down, for example 1 report for $x, 10 reports for $x, etc... however as they pull reports this number needs to go down. To clarify if customer A signs up for 10 reports then his account will show in the database he is signed up for 10 reports, then when he pulls a report that number goes down by one in the database. How would you guys (and gals) do this?

To add to this, the drop down is static, the number of reports remaining per account would be more dynamic in nature, but the starting number of reports would change based on which bulk package they signed up for.

Comment: way too broad. do you have a schema in place? reports for what? stored procedures? SELECT statements? can your users request a copy of a previous report without charge?

Comment: Thanks for the reply randy, yes the drop down is established with 4 options, 4 standard packages. It is structured as `<select><option></option></select>` with 4 options. These go by 1, 10, 25, 50 in the number of reports. I will be storing pdf reports of previously pulled reports online but at a later time. These are commercial credit reports for companies the client company intends to do business with, so I will need to track how many reports are remaining for them every time they pull a report. So say they select the 50 option, they pull a report monday it goes down to 49, etc.

Comment: to add to that, i know `enum` would probably be the route to go for static options but because the value of their option will change every time they pull a report I am not sure how to set it up in the database.

Comment: so where is your trouble? is it with generating reports? or with the database tables? or with the php? or with the server architecture?

Comment: Right now I'm just trying to find the best way to set it up, cause to me it is like combining an `enum` with an `int` ie in the database they could choose from 1, 10, 25, or 50  from the `enum` options, but then it will function as an integer by descending in value every time a report is pulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build some tables similar to this:

```
customer
--------
customer_id
name
other_stuff

report
----------
report_id
url_to_report_on_disk
other_stuff

customer_report
---------------
customer_id
report_id

customer_options
----------------
customer_id
number_reports_purchased
purchase_date
```

then you can count how many reports have been delivered based on the entries in the customer_report table